# Delphi вызвать адрес procedure of object

Tags: delphi, объекты, callback

Есть Callback of object

```
type TTriggerCallback = procedure(Sender: TObject; Props: TBasicTriggerProps) of object;
```

Заношу в список адрес для callback

```
(TriggerList.Objects[Index] as TList).Add(@Callback);
```

Где Callback является процедурой формы

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    TriggerFac := TTriggerFactory.Create;
    TriggerFac.AttachTrigger('OnNoGuiBootChanged', Self.OnNoGuiBootChanged);
end;
```

Но при попытки вызова такой сохраненной функции я получаю Access Violation.

```
var cbkptr: ^TTriggerCallback;

list := TriggerList.Objects[index] as TList;
for I := list.Count-1 downto 0 do begin
    cbkptr := list.Items[i];
    try
        cbkptr^(Sender, Props);
    finally
    end;
end;
```

При это адреса `@Callback` на ввооде и `cbkptr` на выводе одинаковые, похоже что просто не передается объект Self насколько я понимаю. Потому что если убрать of object и передать Self первым параметром то все работает, а таким образом нет.

Есть у кого предложение как можно такое вылечить?

ps: Использую Delphi 7, поэтому `TList<TTriggerCallback>` у меня нету и приходится работать с прямыми адресами.

Comment: `TMethod` *(6 символов нужно...

)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`procedure of object` реализуется в виде записи

```
TMethod = record
  Code: Pointer;
  Data: Pointer;
end;
```

Где `Code` - указатель на сам метод, а `Data` - объект, для которого нужно вызвать метод

Если вам нужно сохранить этот каллбек в список, то нужен такой код

```
procedure AddToList(const ACallback: TTriggerCallback);
var
  LMethod: PMethod;
begin
  GetMem(LMethod, SizeOf(LMethod^));
  LMethod^ := TMethod(ACallback);
  List.Add(LMethod);
end;
```

вызов

```
procedure Invoke(AIndex: Integer; Sender: TObject; Props: TBasicTriggerProps);
var
  LMethod: PMethod;
  LCallback: TTriggerCallback
begin
  LMethod := TMethod(List[AIndex]);
  LCallback := LMethod^;
  LCallback(Sender, Props);
end;
```

Ну и не забыть вызвать `FreeMem` для каждого элемента списка

---

Второй способ - написать объект обертку

```
TTriggerCallbackWraper = class
private
  FCallback: TTriggerCallback;
public
  constructor Create(const ACallback: TTriggerCallback);
public
  property Callback: TTriggerCallback read FCallback;
end;

constructor TTriggerCallbackWraper.Create(const ACallback: TTriggerCallback);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FCallback := ACallback;
end;
```

и добавление

```
procedure AddToList(const ACallback: TTriggerCallback);
begin
  List.Add(TTriggerCallbackWraper.Create(ACallback));
end;
```

вызов

```
(List[Idx] as TTriggerCallbackWraper).Callback(.......)
```

экземпляры класса TTriggerCallbackWraper по окончании работы, должны быть уничтожены вызовом метода `Free`. Или вместо `TList` использовать `TObjectList` с `OwnObjects := True`;

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает! :-) Реально забыл про TMethod.

Comment: Про второй вариант не знал, сейчас попробовал его - тоже очень классная и простая идея!